# What could be the cause for DEADLOCK with two update statements?

Tags: sql-server

I see the deadlock extended event capture two update statements as process which is causing deadlock. Both processes look exactly same.

Process #1:

```
update CL 
set N1 = @P0, N2 = @P1, N3 = @P2 etc.
```

Process #2:

```
update CL 
set N1 = @P0, N2 = @P1, N3 = @P2 etc.
```

Under resource list I see this:

```
<keylock hobtid="72057594321698816" dbid="5" objectname="CLINE" indexname="PK_CLINE" 
<keylock hobtid="72057594320584704" dbid="5" objectname="CL" indexname="PK_CL"
```

I could get the two rows from the %%lockerss%%

What could be the issue?

Comment: <keylock hobtid="72057594321698816" dbid="5" objectname="CLINE" indexname="PK_CLine"

Comment: <keylock hobtid="72057594320584704" dbid="5" objectname="CL" indexname="PK_CL"

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some transactions where you update both tables CI and CLINE (in the same transaction)?
If you have a transaction where you update first CI and then CLINE and another transaction where you update first CLINE and then table CI, this can cause deadlocks.

Comment: Also, look for cascading updates and/or triggers (which both appear to not be part of the affected logic)...since these seem to be kept in lockstep. It wasn't clear from the q whether any of the affected fields were actually keys...but the effect seems to suggest they are.

Comment: And hopefully have some WHERE clause in your updates. Otherwise use serializable transaction isolation level.